# ERROR ITMS-90046 after resign via Fastlane

Tags: ios, fastlane, ios-app-signing

I've the requirement to submit IPA to other team that resign the ipa with different mobile provision profile and certificate.

Prior to enabling Associated domains, it used to work without any hiccups.

When tried to enable associated domains, it gets uploaded on testing apple account. But when trying to upload on live account after resign it gives error.

> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key
>   'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in
>   'Payload/xxxxx.app/xxxxx' is not supported."

Fastlane is being used to resign the app.

Have checked other questions but doesn't fit with using fastlane to resign and uploading via Transporter app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts the only solution that worked for me was to pass the entitlements manually, after signing it via fastlane.

```
unzip -q *.ipa
codesign -f -s "Apple Distribution: Company Name" -i "com.company.project" --entitlements savedEntitlements.plist Payload/*.app/
zip -qr resigned.ipa Payload SwiftSupport Symbols
```